# start embedded Tomcat and open browser from command line

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, tomcat, command-line

I have a java web app that uses embedded Tomcat. I'd like users to open it by executing a single .bat file (Windows).

I use this line for starting Tomcat:

```
java -cp "%cd%\apache-tomcat-8.0.8-embed\*;%cd%" Main
```

(main.java starts Tomcat) and if I put this line next, it won't be executed unless I manually stop Tomcat (Ctrl+C):

```
start http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

If I open the browser first, and start Tomcat after that, then the users will see an error message from the browser for some seconds (while tomcat starts), and they'll panic ;)

Is there a way to return the focus to the script once Tomcat has started?, or some other workaround for this?

In other similar threads, I saw that they could accomplish this, but they were starting tomcat by executing a Tomcat.exe file, which is not my case, since I need to use this embedded version of Tomcat, and start it the way I'm starting it.

The best case scenario would be if I could display a temporary page saying "please wait..." while Tomcat is starting, and when it's done, show my app's initial page (http://127.0.0.1:8080/)

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: If you don't wait for Tomcat to start before launching the browser, there's always going to be a period when users will see a 404 page. You can create a web page that continually pings Tomcat and redirects when it gets 200 (vs 404 when Tomcat not ready).

Comment: That's a good idea!!, I didn't thought of that. I'm going to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply start `java` with the `start` command without interrupting the execution flow of the script. In other words, the script doesn't wait for the `java` process to end before executing the next command.

```
start java -cp "%cd%\apache-tomcat-8.0.8-embed\*;%cd%" Main
```